# Как правильно описать тип history.goBack при передаче из роута?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Подскажите как правильно описать тип history.goBack()?

В Main.ts роут

```
<Route path={PAGE_404} component={Page404} />
```

Компонент Page404

```
const Page404: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <section className={styles.section}>
      <GoBackLink text={'Назад'} onGoBackClick={() => history.goBack()} />
       ...
    </section>
  );
};

export default Page404;
```

Компонент goBackLink в его интерфейсе указано any, но я думаю это не правильно

```
interface IGoBackLinkProps {
  text: string;
  onGoBackClick: any;
}

const GoBackLink: React.FC<IGoBackLinkProps> = ({ text, onGoBackClick }) => {
  return (
    <Link className={styles.link} to='/' onClick={onGoBackClick}>
      {text}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default GoBackLink;
```

Comment: так самое простое посмотреть какой тип у OnClick и сделать такой же

Comment: onGoBackClick: ()=>void

Comment: @Lev Shportak Спасибо!